# Office 365 Site Collection administrator

Tags: sharepoint-online, office-365

I just want to try the office 365 SharePoint Online and I got the trial account for it.

When I created the private site collection the `Administrator` is required. How can I create a user for it? Is it available for trial version?

[image]

Comment: did you try to add your id? i mean under which you log in? did you create any other user accout?

Comment: I try my id and click `Check Name` and It can be through, But it is strange that why my log id can not be seen in the `All Users`. And I didn't know how to create another user account. Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The trial version should be only for 1 user. So you can only use yourself. Even my MSDN Premium doesn't allow more.

Regarding the people picker, mine too show same unless you type some and search.

[image]

Comment: +1 Thanks, I got it . I will appreciate you if you could show some `MSDN` document to read about the limitation of user counts for trial. Because of huge document of `Office 365` and `SharePoint 2013`. It is hard to figure it out for the newbie like me.

Comment: Go to Office 265 Admin --> USERS --> Active Users. Then click new button (the plus sign). Create new user account window will appear. There check 'Select license(s) for this user:' section. It will show whether you have license or not.

Comment: Well, I think it is not explicit to tell the trial user `you need license for Site Collection creation`. Because I can create an account without the license. Right ?

Comment: Yes this is not about site collection creation. Adding a user to the site. Trial users will not have a subscription that can add any more users.